# XAML: how to set TextElement.Name property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime

I am programatically constructing a block of XAML and would like to provide a name `x:Name` to a TextElement object (an Underline in this case) but even though the Name prop provides a setter, it can not be set per this MSDN article:

[`MSDN: TextElement.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.textelement.name.aspx)

> Gets or sets a unique identification for the object. Name can only be set from initial parsing of XAML.

Here is my code:

```
public void AddLink(string token, string text, string uri)
{
    var elem = new Underline();
    elem.Name.Name = token;  // <-- I would expect this would work...

    elem.Inlines.Add();

    if (Container == null)
        Container = new Paragraph();

    Container.Inlines.Add(elem);
}
```

Comment: I love it. This is tagged `[XAML]` but I don't see XAML anywhere here.

Comment: @HighCore HA! was waiting for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I get your question right but to me it seems you are asking to register a name to specific namescope in wpf.

This is what you need:

[`MSDN: FrameworkElement.RegisterName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.registername%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Here is an example:

```
myMainPanel = new StackPanel();
myMainPanel.Background = Brushes.Orange;

button1 = new Button();
button1.Name = "Button1";

// Register button1's name with myMainPanel.
myMainPanel.RegisterName(button1.Name, button1);
button1.Content = "Button 1";
button1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button1Clicked);
myMainPanel.Children.Add(button1);

button2 = new Button();
button2.Name = "Button2";

// Register button2's name with myMainPanel.
myMainPanel.RegisterName(button2.Name, button2);
button2.Content = "Button 2";
button2.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button2Clicked);
myMainPanel.Children.Add(button2);
```